# URL encoding on redirect

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect the user back to a certain URL after a form submit with the following
`header( "refresh:3;url=http://www.XXXX.XXXX/XXXXX/addshotstogamePart2.php?gameNo=$gameNo&roundName=$roundName" );`

which should be something like this

```
http://XXXX.XXXX/XXXX/addshotstogamePart2.php?gameNo=24&roundName=Round+1
```

but what i'm getting is

```
http://XXX.XXX/XXX/addshotstogamePart2.php?gameNo=24&roundName=Round%25201
```

How can i avoid that or fix it?

Comment: Why you don't increment the value before and only overgive `Round`?

Comment: It looks that Round+1 gets url encoded.
Because + is not a valid url symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that Round+1 gets url encoded.
Because + is not a valid url symbol.

1. You can use other symbol, for example ...&roundName=Round_1
2. Or use just number ...&roundName=1
3. You can use no symbol at all ...&roundName=Round1 but then you need to parse that number out of string.

Comment: Did stack force you to post your answer line by line?

Comment: Thank you, ended up parsing the number and form the link without the variable according to the number